# Removing old elements from the time-ordered list

Tags: python, performance, list

Let's say I have a list `l` where each element has an attribute `time` that stores a float representing how many seconds past from some benchmark point. Whenever some event happens, I would like to remove from this list all elements that happened more than `T` seconds before this event, so currently what I do is

```
l = [x in l if x.time > current_time - T]
```

which seems to be a slow way to do things. How can this be done faster? Elements are ordered here by time, so I thought of finding the first element that does not satisfy this condition, e.g.

```
for i, x in enumerate(l):
    if x.time > current_time - T:
         break
l = l[i:]
```

Perhaps there is a beter way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `deque` from `collections`. It gives you `O(1)` complexity to remove element from the head of the list. Since you elements are sorted by time and the oldest is in the head of the list you can easily remove the elements one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Since they're time-ordered, you could use a binary search to find the index of the cut-off point, then re-slice the list. Binary search should be (roughly) O(log n) in finding the cut-off point, then O(n) for the slicing.

However, if you do this frequently, it might be better to use a deque and simply pop elements until the head is "within the period to keep".

So whatever is best would require benchmarking. However, the deque solution is (probably) easier to write, so it might be best to start there, then consider other methods if you are seeing performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

class Element():

    def __init__(self, time):
        self.time = time

l = [ Element(z*5 - random.randrange(6) + 3) for z in range( 21)]
print('list:', [z.time for z in l])
target_time = 72
print('cutoff time:', target_time)


match = False
working_list_from = 0
working_list_to = len(l)
while not match:
    mid = (working_list_to - working_list_from) // 2
    if l[working_list_from + mid].time < target_time:
        working_list_from += mid
    else:
        working_list_to -= mid


    match = (working_list_to - working_list_from) == 1

print(' resulting list', [z.time for z in l[working_list_from+mid:]])
```

results:

```
list: [3, 5, 9, 18, 21, 25, 32, 33, 40, 48, 49, 57, 62, 67, 73, 73, 79, 85, 93, 94, 99]
cutoff time: 72
 resulting list [73, 73, 79, 85, 93, 94, 99]
```